# What is the coordinate-free definition of the Levi-Civita Symbol?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

For clarity I mean the symbol $\epsilon_{ijk}=e_{ijk}/|g|$ where $g$ is the determinant of the metric tensor and $e_{ijk}$ is anti-symmetric in all its indices and $e_{123}=1$. Is there a purely geometrical interpretation that doesn't rely on defining each component as I have done here? For instance the tensor $\delta^i_j$ can be defined in terms of its components (1 when $i=j$ otherwise 0) or by saying its the identity transform on the tangent space.

An example of the usage is to define a dual vector to a given tensor via $a_i=\epsilon_{ijk}A^{jk}$, so I would also appreciate answers that give a coordinate independent way of understanding this statement.

Comment: Sounds like you should read about [the volume form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form#Riemannian_volume_form) and [tensor densities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density).

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis yes that first link seems to point towards what I want to know, which is that $\epsilon = \epsilon_{ijk} dx^i dx^j dx^j = dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$. Seems I need to learn more about differential forms and hodge duals.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is the evaluation of a basic k-form in a set of $k$ basic vectors:
$$\varepsilon^1\wedge\varepsilon^2\wedge...\wedge\ \varepsilon^k
\ (e_{i_1},e_{i_2},...,e_{i_k})=\epsilon_{i_1i_2...i_k}$$
where $\varepsilon^r(e_s)=\delta^r{}_s$, here $\varepsilon^r$ being 
its dual basis.

Consider the next instance:
if we have a base change 
$$b_1=Ae_1+Be_2$$ 
and 
$$b_2=Ce_1+De_2$$
then
$$\varepsilon^1\wedge\varepsilon^2(b_1,b_2)
=\varepsilon^1\wedge\varepsilon^2(Ae_1+Be_2,Ce_1+De_2).$$
So
$$\varepsilon^1\wedge\varepsilon^2(b_1,b_2)=AD-BC$$
and this is geometrical since $AD-BC$ is the area spawned by the new base $b_1,b_2$.

Comment: If we set $$\varepsilon^1\wedge\varepsilon^2\wedge...\wedge\ \varepsilon^k
\ (b_{i_1},b_{i_2},...,b_{i_k})$$ for another base, guess what are you going to find?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can't quite figure this out till the end, but maybe with the help of comments we can finish it off.

Let's assume for simplicity that $A^{ij}$ is a real matrix, as complex matrices and geometry simultaneously are a bit past my ability to imagine. Anyway, any real matrix can be decomposed into symmetric and antisymmetric part

$$A = \frac{A+A^T}{2} + \frac{A-A^T}{2} = B + C$$

It should be easy to see that Levi-Civita operation on the symmetric part is zero $\epsilon_{ijk}B^{jk} = 0$. So only the anti-symmetric part is left.

In 3D, an arbitrary anti-symmetric matrix can be written with the help of Levi-Civita symbol as

$$C_{ij} = \epsilon_{ijk}c^k$$ where $c^k$ is an arbitrary 3D vector. Thus, the full operation OP has requested can be written as

$$\epsilon_{ijk}A^{jk} = \epsilon_{ijk}C^{jk} = \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon^{jkl}c_l = 2\delta_i^l c_l = 2c_i$$

Since $C_{ij}x^j = -\vec{c} \times \vec{x}$, the original operation $\epsilon_{ijk}A^{jk} = 2c_i$ can be interpreted as

> "For the part of the mapping $A$ that acts as a cross-product, extract
>   negative twice the vector that would be cross-producted with".

I think my wording is a bit clumsy. Perhaps colleagues that are more fresh on fluid dynamics would be able to rewrite the above statement in terms of something like vorticity

Comment: I'd rather have a definition that's more geometric if possible? For instance the Kronecker delta I have a satisfactory definition of what tensor I am dealing with, and the $i=j$ business is just what its components turn out to be. How do I characterise $\epsilon$ in this way?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled. As far as I'm concerned, my definition is completely coordinate-free. It only mentions the cross-product, not the elements of the matrix. Perhaps you can mention any other tensor, except Kronecker delta, that has, in your view, a clear geometric meaning, so that I know what you are looking for?